# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent

Tags: automation

Unable to launch WebDriverAgent. Original error: xcodebuild failed with code 65. This usually indicates an issue with the local Xcode setup or WebDriverAgent project configuration or the driver-to-platform version mismatch

Whenever i start session in appium inspector, can someone help?, where i was try to inspect element in my real IOS device